# How to parallelize file writing using TPL?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, task-parallel-library

I am trying to save list of strings to multiple files, each string in a different file, and do it simultaneously. I do it like this:

```
public async Task SaveToFilesAsync(string path, List<string> list, CancellationToken ct)
{
    int count = 0;
    foreach (var str in list)
    {
        string fullPath = path + @"\" + count.ToString() + "_element.txt";
        using (var sw = File.CreateText(fullPath))
        {
            await sw.WriteLineAsync(str);
        }
        count++;

        NLog.Trace("Saved in thread: {0} to {1}", 
           Environment.CurrentManagedThreadId,
           fullPath);

        if (ct.IsCancellationRequested)
            ct.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
    }
}
```

And call it like this:

```
try
{
   var savingToFilesTask = SaveToFilesAsync(@"D:\Test", myListOfString, ct);
}
catch(OperationCanceledException)
{
   NLog.Info("Operation has been cancelled by user.");
}
```

But in log file I can clearly see that saving always happen in the same thread id, so no parallelism is going on? What am I doing wrong? How to fix it? My goal is make all saving as fast as possible using all computer cores.

Comment: Your operation runs asynchronously, but not in parallel, there's a difference. You can parallelize the loop, but I don't think it's going to yield any improvement - your operation is not CPU bound, but IO bound...

Comment: It's highly unlikely that your CPU will be the bottleneck. I/O is several orders of magnitude slower. No need to parallelize for this, you'll only slow the processing down if you're using mechanical hard drives.

Comment: Are you running a GUI application?

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov no, it's a console app

Answer (score 4):

Essentially, your problem is `foreach` is synchronous. It uses `IEnumerable` which is synchronous.

To work around this, first encapsulate the loop body into an asynchronous function.

```
public async Task WriteToFile(
        string path,
        string str,
        int count)
{
    var fullPath = string.Format("{0}\\{1}_element.txt", path, count);
    using (var sw = File.CreateText(fullPath))
    {
        await sw.WriteLineAsync(str);
    }

    NLog.Trace("Saved in TaskID: {0} to \"{1}\"", 
       Task.CurrentId,
       fullPath);
}
```

Then, instead of looping synchronously, project the sequence of strings to a sequence of tasks performing your encapsulated loop body. This is not a asynchronous operation in itself but the projection will not block, i.e. there is no `await`.

Then wait for them all tasks to finish in an order defined by the Task Scheduler.

```
public async Task SaveToFilesAsync(
        string path,
        IEnumerable<string> list,
        CancellationToken ct)
{
    await Task.WhenAll(list.Select((str, count) => WriteToFile(path, str, count));
}
```

There is nothing to cancel, so there is no point passing the cancellation token down.

I've used the indexing overload of `Select` to provide the `count` value.

I've changed your logging code to use the current Task ID, this avoids any confusion around scheduling.

Comment: In reality, it *can* prove beneficial because IO operations involve more than actual IO. They include buffering at the framework and OS level, CPU-bound operations like serialization etc, security checks and other ops that prevent the drive from working at full speed.  Even with "pure" IO bound operations like copying files, multithreading can improve speed. Try running `robocopy` with the /MT option.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, I think the note probably distracts from the answer (I've removed it). I don't think the question is really about the merits of this approach in a real world situation. It it were I'd have to suggest something different.

Comment: You might want to use PLINQ's [`Select`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383966(v=vs.100).aspx) with a [limited max degree of parallelism](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383719(v=vs.100).aspx) instead of normal LINQ's `Select`, while processing multiple files may provide a boot processing too many files at once will cause a performance drop.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain, you make a good point, if my scenario was more complicated I'd probably use TPL.Dataflow, I find it suprisingly useful. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh228603(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 2):

If you want to do that parallel you have to tell .NET to do so.
I think one of the easiest ways to do this becomes clear if you split up your code into a additional function.

The idea is to split the actual single IO operation into a additional async function and call those function without awaiting them, but with storing them created tasks in a list and awaiting all of them at the end.

I am not writing C# code usually, so please excuse any syntax error I might did:

```
public async Task SaveToFilesAsync(string path, List<string> list, CancellationToken ct)
{
    int count = 0;
    var writeOperations = new List<Task>(list.Count);
    foreach (var str in list)
    { 
        string fullPath = path + @"\" + count.ToString() + "_element.txt";
        writeOperations.add(SaveToFileAsync(fullPath, str, ct));
        count++;
        ct.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
    }

    await Task.WhenAll(writeOperations);
}

private async Task SaveToFileAsync(string path, string line, CancellationToken ct)
{
    using (var sw = File.CreateText(path))
    {
        await sw.WriteLineAsync(line);
    }

    NLog.Trace("Saved in thread: {0} to {1}", 
        Environment.CurrentManagedThreadId, 
        fullPath);

    ct.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
}
```

This way the IO operations are triggered once after another by the same thread. That should work very fast. And the continuation is triggered once the IO operation is done using the .NET ThreadPool.

I also removed the `if (ct.IsCancellationRequested)` check because that is done by `ct.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();` anyway.

Hope that gives you a idea how to go about those things.

Comment: That is correct, but does not matter as every writing operation writes to a different file. So the order is not of interest. Also the number is maintained by the outer function, so the numbering of the files will be correct.

Answer (score 1):

If this is on parallel storage (SSD) you might be able to make this faster by parallelizing. Since there is no built-in way to parallelize async loops with a certain degree of parallelism I'd recommend PLINQ with a fixed degree of parallelism and synchronous IO. `Parallel.ForEach` cannot be made to have a fixed DOP (only a max DOP).

Answer (score 1):

I've added my answer in the original question, should I add it here instead?
[C# TPL calling tasks in a parallel manner and asynchronously creating new files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31015213/c-sharp-tpl-calling-tasks-in-a-parallel-manner-and-asynchronously-creating-new-f/31016000#31016000)

**Edit**: Here's the proposed solution now running multiple save in parallel.

You need to replace the foreach loop, which runs sequentially from the first to the last item, with a Parallel.ForEach() loop that can be configured for parallelism.

```
var cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
Task.WaitAll(SaveFilesAsync(@"C:\Some\Path", files, cts.Token));
cts.Dispose();
```

Then do your parallelism in that method.

```
public async Task SaveFilesAsync(string path, List<string> list, CancellationToken token)
{
    int counter = 0;

    var options = new ParallelOptions
                      {
                          CancellationToken = token,
                          MaxDegreeOfParallelism = Environment.ProcessorCount,
                          TaskScheduler = TaskScheduler.Default
                      };

    await Task.Run(
        () =>
            {
                try
                {
                    Parallel.ForEach(
                        list,
                        options,
                        (item, state) =>
                            {
                                // if cancellation is requested, this will throw an OperationCanceledException caught outside the Parallel loop
                                options.CancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

                                // safely increment and get your next file number
                                int index = Interlocked.Increment(ref counter);
                                string fullPath = string.Format(@"{0}\{1}_element.txt", path, index);

                                using (var sw = File.CreateText(fullPath))
                                {
                                    sw.WriteLine(item);
                                }

                                Debug.Print(
                                    "Saved in thread: {0} to {1}",
                                    Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId,
                                    fullPath);
                            });
                }
                catch (OperationCanceledException)
                {
                    Debug.Print("Operation Canceled");
                }
            });
}
```

Comment: Go for it, I need to use Tasks, but interesting solution though

Comment: I'm lost... need to use tasks? The solution I suggest is the same as your code above, but changes your foreach loop to a parallel loop running multiple save simultaneously.

Comment: sorry, I looked at different solution, not yours

Comment: No problem, if that's not what you are looking for. I just don't get what you mean by "I need to use tasks".